# how to specify multiple formats for date validation

Tags: validation, date, datetime, yii2

I have a model which has 2 date attributes and I want them to be valid for different date formats, such as: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss(here should be a format for timezone and microtime)`, but it seems that `format` property of validation rule does not accept an array. Now I wonder is there any way to do this with date validator or I can use only regular expression validator?
Here is a rule which I am using now:

```
[['adtime', 'uptime'], 'date', 'type' => DateValidator::TYPE_DATETIME, 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple validation rules for the same attributes. `Yii` will test each rule, if it fails that rule it goes on to the next rule until it runs out of rules, then it fails validation. so you can simply do;

```
[['adtime', 'uptime'], 'date', 'type' => DateValidator::TYPE_DATETIME, 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'],
[['adtime', 'uptime'], 'date', 'type' => DateValidator::TYPE_DATETIME, 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'],
```